# What layout should I use?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm making a clicker game as a school project.
I'm using the Xamarin (Android) project.
What layout should I use for the main screen? It will look like this (buttons):
[Main Screen Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79c47.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the design you give, we can use `RelativeLayout` as the root element.

`RelativeLayout` is a `ViewGroup` that displays child View elements in relative positions. The position of a View can be specified as relative to sibling elements (such as to the `left-of` or `below` a given element) or in positions relative to the `RelativeLayout` area (such as aligned to the bottom, left of center).

For more information, you can check document: [Xamarin.Android RelativeLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout) .

For the inner elements, you can decide which layout(e.g. `LinearLayout`,`TableLayout` ) to use based on your situation.

**Update:**

> Will Frame Layout work too?

From document [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout), we could find that:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
> a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
> child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
> way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
> overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a
> FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by
> assigning gravity to each child, using the `android:layout_gravity`
> attribute.

You can use other layouts, such as the FrameLayout you said, but as far as your design is concerned, RelativeLayout is more suitable.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will Frame Layout work too?

Comment: Yes, you can use other layouts, such as the `FrameLayout` you said, but as far as your design is concerned, `RelativeLayout` is more suitable.